# Uninitialized constant after upgrade rails 5.2 to 6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

After upgrading my RoR app to 6.0, I'm getting this error:
`NameError: uninitialized constant Sites::NetworkResolver::ExternalApi`. This is my `app/resolvers/sites/network_resolver.rb` file:

```rb
module Sites
  class NetworkResolver
    ExternalApi::Graphql
    ...
  end
end
```

and my `app/services/external_api/graphql.rb`

```rb
module ExternalApi
  module Graphql
   ...
  end 
end
```

in the `app/services` folder, I have a settings file with the same name `external_api.rb`

```rb
module ExternalApi
  ...
end
```

```bash
rails zeitwerk:check 
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Sites::NetworkResolver::ExternalApi
```

If I put it at the top of `app/resolvers/network_resolver.rb` file

```rb
require 'external_api/graphql'
```

I need to update `externalApi` to `externalAPI` so that Api is uppercase

```bash
app/services/external_api/graphql.rb to define constant ExternalAPI::Graphql, but didn't
```

so code works but didn't want to update more than 100 files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `app/resolvers/network_resolver.rb` should define `NetworkResolver`, rather than `Sites:: NetworkResolver`, maybe the path is mistaken?

You can force inflection for `external_api` to not use the acronym this way:

```
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb
Rails.autoloaders.main.inflector.inflect("external_api" => "ExternalApi")
```

Comment: yeah, that works with force inflector. Thank you so much!